# How to pass props in Link and Route component at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I get a one main Parent component which is display all the time, and this component connects to api to get an authorization key. I route only between components which are inside him and i need to pass authorization from Parent compo to component called *Playlist* what i do like that:

```
<Route path="/playlists" component={() => <Playlists authKey={auth} />} />
```

But i also need to pass props from other Child component (where is the link to playlists) what i do like that:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/playlists', myProps: { name: 'some name' }}}
```

The problem is that in props of *Playlist* component I get only data that i pass inside **Route** compo but i need also data from props passed inside **Link**

Answer (score 0):

You could include the parameter in the URL. Declare your path as:

```
<Route path="/playlists/:name" component={() => <Playlists authKey={auth} />} />
```

Then set your link to lead to it:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/playlists/some_name'}} />
```

And then access it, using:

```
const name = this.props.match.params.name
```

Comment: That's really helpfull, but now I got undefined when i pass object as a state parameter

Comment: Well, that is normal, because in the URL, you can just set strings/numbers/bools and other primitive types only.

Comment: That's right, but in the URL I pass only the name parameter, rest of the object i pass as state: { key: value }. Now i realized that I need to set also *search* and *hash* parameter to get access to state :) Thank's for your time